# how to recover deleted rows from MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

Today morning I surprisingly found that some data is deleted form my MYSQL database, I am unable to find that data in any table.

Please suggest how to recover data from MySQL database, DOES MYSQL keeps any Log if yes where it is located? 
Please suggest any query to get all records.

I am using MYSQL Workbench 5.

Comment: no i have not scheduled backup

Comment: happy to inform you i have replaced mytable.ibd files , i found those by recovery tool , i found my data but unfortunately MuSql is not starting , please suggest

Answer (score 5):

If you have binary logs active on your server then you can use `mysqlbinlog`

You can use the following:

```
mysqlbinlog binary_log_file > query_log.sql
```

If you don't have this, then you have probably lost it.

You can look [here](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/restore-dropped-mysql-database-from-binary-logs) for more information on how to convert the **binary logs** to **sql**.

You can check if binary logging is enabled or not by running the following command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';
```

Comment: more info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog.html

Comment: does mysql bydefault activates Binary log at the time of installation .?

Comment: @RohitJape Yes, you can. You can do it by typing `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';`

Comment: happy to inform you i have replaced mytable.ibd files , i found those by recovery tool , i found my data but unfortunately MySql is not starting , please suggest

Comment: @RohitJape Check this answer

Comment: pl upload link again

Answer (score 0):

For InnoDB tables, if binary logs are not enabled, there is a recovery [tool](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/02/20/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-an-innodb-tablespace/) provided by Percona which may help.

Created a [script](https://github.com/VanagaS/mysql-innodb-autorecover) to automate the steps from the Percona tool which recovers the deleted rows (if exist) and provides SQL queries to load the data into database.

Please note:

> The time between the deletion of rows and the database stop is
> crucial. If pages are reused you can’t recover the data.